# Resource units used for a graph request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the following code to find the count of users in AAD group:

```
var requestUrl = _graphClient.Groups[objectId.ToString()].TransitiveMembers.Request().RequestUrl;
requestUrl = $"{requestUrl}/microsoft.graph.user/$count";
var hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
hrm.Headers.Add("ConsistencyLevel", "eventual");
await _graphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);
var r = await _graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
var content = await r.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var userCount = int.Parse(content);
return userCount;
```

Is there a way to find out the resource units used for this request (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits), the resource unit cost for `GET groups/{id}/transitiveMembers` is 5.

[image]

But using `$count` affects the cost. If you send the request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/transitivemembers/microsoft.graph.user/$count
```

and check the response headers there should be header [x-ms-resource-unit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling-limits#regular-responses-requests) which indicates the resource unit cost used for this request and it's **1**.

[image]

Get header x-ms-resource-unit

```
var r = await _graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
var cost = r.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-resource-unit").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean the resource unit cost for the above code is 1 (minimum)? Also, the above code I have - does it read entire users in the group and get the count? OR does it just read count?

Comment: Also, how do I get x-ms-resource-unit from my above code?

Comment: it read just count. To get response header x-ms-resource-unit in your code use var cost = r.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-resource-unit").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Also, can you please let me know x-ms-resource-unit header value for https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id eq 'id'

Comment: I don't see "x-ms-resource-unit" header for graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/delta?$filter=id eq 'id' Why is that?

Comment: @user989988 If x-ms-resource-unit is missing then unit cost should be 1. According to the doc: GET operation for any identity path not listed in the table (groups/delta is not liste) the unit cost is 1. The documentation should definitely clarify when x-ms-resource-unit header is included in the response.